# What are these grey dashed guide lines in Flash?

Tags: flash, fla

img: http://tinypic.com/r/34raqvm/5

I received a Flash project from an outside source. In it I found that some library items had these grey, dashed guide lines. It seems like they are used for assigning resize boundaries or something. Anyways, I can't reproduce them in my own library elements nor can I find any information on them. What terms should I use to google so I can read up on these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly. It's called 9-slice scaling.

http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/scale9/

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_9-slice.html

Comment: Excellent! I knew it was something simple I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: The two links are dead. Wayback-machine entry for the first link https://web.archive.org/web/20111129111611/http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/scale9. There isn't one for the second.